# New line not detected in Regex in Redshift regexp_instr

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a few strings string like this

"src=
https://media.hello.com/abc/def.png
xyz"

"src=
https://media.hello.com/tys/sdfjkhsdkjf.png 
xyz"

"src=https://media.hello.com/tysds/sxsdsa.dfjkhsdkjf.jpeg&xyz"

Now I want to create a regex which could give me records where this kind of url is present. I am using this query to search for matching records in Redshift.

select *
from table where
regexp_instr(column_name, '(((media.hello.com)|(abcd123.cloudfront.net)).*?)(?=\?(&| |\n))',1,1,0,'ip') > 0

Note 1 : I am able to get results from above query if I exclude '\n'. I have tried adding it different ways like [\n], \n but that didn't help.

Note 2: Even if I use the regex : 'https?://\S', I am not able to get a match in redshift.
I have also tried both these following statements but they didn't work.
and column_name ~ 'https?://\S+.(png|jpg)'
and regexp_instr(column_name, 'https?://\S+.(png|jpg)',1,1,0,'ip') > 0

Comment: Try regex101, there ypu can test your regular expression

Comment: My regex is matching correctly there, but fails to match in redshift query

Comment: There exist differenr stanndards, you need to check which redshift supports

Comment: Your regex is looking for matches containing one of two possible (sub)domains, which btw should be `((media\.hello\.com)|(abcd123\.cloudfront\.net))`., followed by a question mark then one of an ampersand, space, or newline. `(?=\?[& \n])` in the form of an assertion. This does not match anything. Your question is a red herring referring to a newline problem. I was going to help with a regex but found your explanation dubious.

Comment: @sln skipped a part of regex earlier. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the complete regex in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `\\\\n` instead of "\n"